# Reconstruction of selected part in an image

Tags: python, opencv

I have a program that selects a region and fill it with a specific color.
I need to reconstruct the image.
please help.
Thanks in advance.

The program for selecting the boundary and filling is below

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import sys

def is_equal(a, b):
    _equal = a[0]==b[0] and a[1]==b[1] and a[2]==b[2]
    return _equal

sys.setrecursionlimit(30000)

def boundary_fill(src, x, y, fill_color, boundary_color):
    try:
        color_at_xy = src[y, x]
    except (IndexError,RuntimeError):
        return
    if not is_equal(color_at_xy,fill_color) and not is_equal(color_at_xy,boundary_color):
        src[y, x] = fill_color
        boundary_fill(src, x + 1, y, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x - 1, y, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x, y - 1, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x, y + 1, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x + 1, y - 1, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x + 1, y + 1, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x - 1, y - 1, fill_color, boundary_color)
        boundary_fill(src, x - 1, y + 1, fill_color, boundary_color)

ix,iy = -1,-1
drawing = False # true if mouse is pressed
pressed = False
boundary_mode = True

# mouse callback function
def draw_boundary(event,former_x,former_y,flags,param):
    global current_former_x,current_former_y,drawing, boundary_mode, pressed
    if boundary_mode:
        if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            pressed=True
            current_former_x,current_former_y=former_x,former_y

    elif event==cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if pressed == True:
            drawing = True
            cv2.line(im,(current_former_x,current_former_y),(former_x,former_y),(0,0,255),2)
            current_former_x = former_x
            current_former_y = former_y
    elif event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        if drawing:
            drawing=False
            cv2.line(im,(current_former_x,current_former_y),(former_x,former_y),(0,0,255),2)
            current_former_x = former_x
            current_former_y = former_y
        pressed = False
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        print ix,iy
        boundary_fill(im, former_x, former_y, (255,255,255), (0,0,255))
    return former_x,former_y  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    render = True
    im = cv2.imread("src.jpg")
    cv2.namedWindow("Bound")
    cv2.setMouseCallback('Bound',draw_boundary)
    while(render):
        cv2.imshow('Bound',im)
        k = cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF     
        if k==27:
            render = False

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]
input image

[image]
output image

Comment: can you clarify what is your question? you're only saying: "i have a program, please help". Is your program failing?

Comment: What do you mean by "reconstruct"? You already have the original image.

Comment: **reconstruct means : i have an image and i need to remove some parts in it and i select that region and painted it in white. i need to fill those region with reference to its neighboring pixels**